# is there a regex for PDF font-family and font-names

Tags: pdf, fonts

I am working with FontNames from PDF documents and wish to convert them to one of the 14 standard fonts if possible. An example is:

```
KAIKCD+Helvetica-Oblique
```

Are there standards for the punctuation and values of the pre/suf/fixes? I have found both `-Oblique` `.I` and `-Italic` as suffixes all - presumably - meaning Italic. Or are the names semantically void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix is as defined in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> For a font subset, the PostScript name of the font — the value of the
>   font’s BaseFont entry and the font descriptor’s FontName entry — shall
>   begin with a tag followed by a plus sign (+). The tag shall consist of
>   exactly six uppercase letters; the choice of letters is arbitrary, but
>   different subsets in the same PDF file shall have different tags.

Otherwise there merely are some common naming patterns; Jon Tan has tried to catalogue some [here](http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/naming/).